How many different 8 characters passwords with 2 upper-case 2 digits 4 lower-case
A web-banking password is always 8 characters long and it always comprises two upper-case letters from the standard English alphabet, two digits, and four lower-case letters from the standard English alphabet. How many different passwords can be created that follow these rules?

Let "UUddllll" mean 2 repeated uppercase letters (U), 2 repeated digits (d), 4 repeated lowercase letters (l).
There are $\frac{8!}{2!2!4!}$=420 permutations and
26 * 26 * 10 choices for U l and d.
"UUddalll" means choose any lower case letter (a), then a different lower case letter but with 3 repetitions.
$ \frac{8!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 3!} $ permutations * 26 * 10 * 26 * 25 choices for U d a and l.
"UUddabll" means choose any lower case letter (a), then a different lower case letter (b) and another lower case letter (l) with 2 repetitions.
$ \frac{8!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!} $ permutations * 26 * 10 * 26 * 25 * 24 choices for U d a b l.
"UUddabcl"
$ \frac{8!}{2! \cdot 2!} $ * 26 * 10 * 26 * 25 * 24 * 23 choices.
"UUdDabcl" means choose any digit (d), then a different digit (D).
$ \frac{8!}{2!} $ permutations * 26 * 10 * 9 * 26 * 25 * 24 * 23 choices for U d D a b c and l.
"UudDabcl" means all choices are different.
$ 8! $ permutations * 26 * 25 * 10 * 9 * 26 * 25 * 24 * 23 choices for U u d D a b c and l.
final result = sum of the above products
Is this correct?

You seem to have "UUlldddd" but "two upper-case letters from the standard English alphabet, two digits, and four lower-case letters".  What are A, B, C?

It is not clear how you are separating the various cases.

As you edit your posted question, to correct the fact that you have 2 digits and 4 lower case, rather than 4 digits and 2 lower case, there are two other aspects that you may wish to consider.  For one thing, focusing (for example) only on the $~2~$ upper case letters, assuming that repeats are allowed, the number of different pairs of upper case letters is simply $~(26)^2.~$  ...see next comment

Further, the first factor of $$\displaystyle \binom{8}{4} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2} = 420$$ completely determines which 4 positions receive the lower case letters, then, which 2 positions receive the upper case letters, then, which 2 positions receive the digits.  ...see next comment

Going forward, with this posted question, and any of your future MathSE posted questions, as you proofread your question, consider the viewpoint of your audience.  Is it crystal clear exactly what you are trying to say (regardless of whether there is or is not an analytical mistake)?  You don't want to require MathSE reviewers to have to guess at what you intend.  Having to guess makes it difficult for the reviewer to determine whether your analysis is accurate.

Thank you for your comment, I have corrected the question, could you please have another look?

With generating function:
$$
[x^2y^4z^2] (26x+26y+10z)^8 \\
= [x^2y^4z^2] \sum_{a=0}^8 \sum_{b=0}^{8-a} \frac{8!}{a!b!(8-a-b)!}(26x)^a(26y)^b(10z)^{8-a-b} \\
= \frac{8!}{2!4!2!}26^2 26^4 10^2
= 12974462592000 
$$
To explain the result: When you have the basic word (with place holders for big, small and numbers), simply fill each category enlotment with allowing repeatition. There are $\frac{8!}{2!4!2!}$ basic words and each has $26^2 26^4 10^2$ different fillings. You don't have to go to different cases of how many repeats there are.


"...Is this correct..."

Your posted analysis seems very bizarre to me.  Based on the posted question:

There are $~420~$ different ways that the two upper case characters, two digits, and four lower case letters can be positioned in the $~8~$ character password.

There are $~(26)^2~$ possibilities for the two upper case letters. 
There are $~(10)^2~$ possibilities for the two digits. 
There are $~(26)^4~$ possibilities for the four lower case letters.


So, if I have not misinterpreted the problem, the final enumeration is simply
$$420 \times (26)^2 \times (10)^2 \times (26)^4.$$
Have I interpreted the question correctly?
If not, what is my misinterpretation?
If so, then do you agree that your attempt to analyze cases where (for example) the first lower case letter is different from the other lower case letters is completely unnecessary?
